# What if the partial derivates don't equal to zero for any value, how to find the critical point?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

Given the function: $f(x,y) = \cos y\cdot e^x$
Question is to determine the nature of its critical points.
I've calculated the partial derivatives as following :

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x,y)=\cos y\cdot e^x$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x,y)=-\sin y\cdot e^x$

None of these can equal to zero does that mean that the function doesn't have a critical point or is there another method?

Comment: Hint: $e^x$ is never zero. The sine and cosine functions definitely have zeros.

Comment: There are no critical points.

Comment: @SeanRoberson They do have zeros, but never at the same point...

Comment: so it doesn't have an extrema ?

Comment: @Jazmine correct.

Comment: It will only have extrema if you consider constraints. For instance, it will have extrema in the set defined by $x^2+y^2=1$.

Comment: To visualize what's happening: if you take a cross section along $x=a$ for some $a$, you'll get a cosine wave, scaled by a factor $e^a$. If there were an extremum, it would be at one of the peaks or valleys of this curve (i.e., $y=\pi n$ for some $n$). But if you consider a cross section along $y=b$, you get an exponential curve $(\cos b)e^x$, which has no critical point unless the factor $\cos b$ is zero; this will be at the nodes $y=\frac \pi 2 + \pi n$. Try piecing together these images in your mind, or even drawing the function.

Comment: You might imagine this function as wavy as $y$ changes and increasingly wavy as $x$ increases.  If you are at any point where $\cos(y) \not= 0$ you can get to a higher or lower point by slightly changing $x$; if you are at any point where $\cos(y) \not= \pm1$ you can get to a higher or lower point by slightly changing $y$.  So there are no critical points since $\cos(y)$ cannot be both $0$ and $\pm1$ at the same time

Comment: I got it thank you all !

Answer (score 2):

Function $f$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}^2$. By definition, its critical points satisfy the stationarity conditions you mentioned. Since those conditions are not met at any point $(x,y)$, we conclude that $f$ has no critical points.